# Is $\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\in L^1[\pi,\infty]$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I am trying to prove that 
$$
F(y)=\int_\pi^\infty\frac{e^{-xy}\sin x}{x}\,dx
$$
is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. My first though was to try and show that $F$ is Lipschitz which led me to the following inequality:
$$
\lvert F(y_1)-F(y_2)\rvert\le\int_\pi^\infty \left\lvert\frac{\sin x}{x} \right\rvert\cdot\lvert e^{-xy_1}-e^{-xy_2}\rvert\,dx.
$$
Then I wanted to apply Holder's inequality to get
$$
\lvert F(y_1)-F(y_2)\rvert\le\int_\pi^\infty \left\lvert\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rvert\cdot\lvert e^{-xy_1}-e^{-xy_2}\rvert\,dx\le\left\|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\|_1\cdot\|e^{-xy_1}-e^{-xy_2}\|_\infty,
$$
but it occurs to me that I don't know that $\left\|\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right\|_1$ exists. I know that
$$
\int_{\pi}^\infty \frac{\sin{x}}{x}\,dx\le\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2},
$$
but that doesn't help me with
$$
\int_\pi^\infty \left\lvert\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rvert\,dx.
$$
Any thoughts?

UPDATE:

With some input from my friends, I have decided I can switch the norms on my functions and get
$$
\begin{align*}
\lvert F(y_1)-F(y_2)\rvert&\le\int_{\pi}^\infty \left\lvert\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rvert\cdot\lvert e^{-xy_1}-e^{-xy_2}\rvert\,dx\\
&\le\left\|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\|_\infty\cdot\|e^{-xy_1}-e^{-xy_2}\|_1\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\lvert e^{-y_1\pi}-e^{-y_2\pi}\rvert\\
&\le\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\lvert y_1\pi-y_2\pi\rvert\\
&=\lvert y_1-y_2\rvert.
\end{align*}
$$
Thus $F(y)$ is Lipschitz and therefore differentiable a.e. on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: sin(x)/x is not $L^1(\pi,+\infty)$

Comment: In fact that $L_1$-norm is infinite.

Comment: That is what I thought. Perhaps I should switch the norms? Certainly $\sin{x}/x$ is essentially bounded on $[\pi,\infty)$.

Comment: yes, sin(x)/x is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You are almost there!

Comment: I think dominated convergence theorem would be simpler and give the stronger result that it is everywhere differentiable on $(0,\infty)\,.$

Comment: The followup question was to calculate the derivative. I ended up using dominated convergence to get the answer there. I suppose just calculating the derivate cuts to the chase though, right?

Comment: Yes, but you need to show that it converges to what you think it should converge to, and that's probably easiest to do using dominated convergence theorem. I'm not sure you can do this your way directly.

Comment: Well, all I wanted to show was that it was a differentiable function. I wasn't necessarily calculating the actual derivative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{\pi n}^{\pi(n+1)}\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|\,dx \geq \int_{\pi \left(n+\frac{1}{4}\right)}^{\pi \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)}\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|\,dx&\geq& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\pi \left(n+\frac{1}{4}\right)}^{\pi \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)}\frac{dx}{x}\\&\geq&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\pi \left(n+\frac{1}{4}\right)}^{\pi \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)}\frac{dx}{\pi \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)}\\&=&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4n+3}\end{eqnarray*}$$
but since $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4n+3}$ is divergent, $\frac{\sin x}{x}\color{red}{\not\in} L^1(\pi,+\infty).$

As pointed by [Dr.MV](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/218419/dr-mv) in the comments, integration by parts leads to the stronger inequality:
$$ \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\,dx \geq \frac{2}{\pi(n+1)}.$$

About differentiability, it is enough to get rid of the sine through:
$$\left|F(y_1)-F(y_2)\right|\leq\int_{\pi}^{+\infty}\frac{\left|e^{-xy_1}-e^{-x y_2}\right|}{x}\,dx.$$

Comment: @JackD'urizio Would not the inequality $\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|dx\ge \frac{2}{(n+1)\pi}$ be more immediate and direct?

Comment: @Dr.MV: probably so. Is that trivial?

Comment: Now I see, that follows from integration by parts, true.

Comment: $\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|dx\ge \frac{1}{(n+1)\pi}\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} |\sin x|dx=  \frac{1}{(n+1)\pi}|(-1)^n-(-1)^{n+1}|= \frac{2}{(n+1)\pi}$.  Hope this is somehow useful.